# Python: Collect return values from threaded functions

Tags: python, multithreading

I have written this sample code that generate random numbers using multiple threads.

I can print each random number without any problems. But what I am trying to achieve is, I want to collect all the returned integers into `generated_numbers` array.

```py
from random import randint
from threading import Thread
import time


def generate_random_number(n):
    time.sleep(randint(0, 99)*0.01)
    random_number = randint(0, 99)
    print(str(n) + 'th random number: ' + str(random_number))
    return random_number


generated_numbers = []

for i in range(1, 100):
    thread = Thread(target=generate_random_number, args=(i,))
    thread.start()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) instead of [threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html), with the [Pool](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool) class you can map a function `generate_random_number` to an iterable `range(1,100)`.

Here is an example that does what you want:

*N.B. 100 threads is a little overkill for such a small iterable.*

```
import multiprocessing
from random import randint


def generate_random_number(n):
    random_number = randint(0, 99)
    return f'{n}th random number: {random_number}'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(100)
    generated_numbers = pool.map(generate_random_number, range(100))
    print(generated_numbers)
```

Comment: This helped! thanks :) Of course it's an overkill, this was just a dummy code used only for the question.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like

```
from random import randint
from threading import Thread
import time


def generate_random_number(n):
    global generated_numbers
    time.sleep(randint(0, 99)*0.01)
    random_number = randint(0, 99)
    print(str(n) + 'th random number: ' + str(random_number))
    generated_numbers.append(random_number)
    return random_number


generated_numbers = []

threads = [Thread(target=generate_random_number, args=(i,)) for i in range(100)]
for thread in threads:
    thread.start()

[t.join() for t in threads]
print generated_numbers
```

t.join() will wait for thread to execute, we are doing this by using list comprehension as thread.join() would resolve once last thread has completed which could happen before all of the started threads run.

Comment: I am not so sure about this solution, it works. but is modifying a global list from multiple threads safe?

Comment: Not sure if its safe to be honest, alternative is using queue with multitheading @nipunasudha

Comment: I guess it depends. In CPython it would be safe because of the global interpreter lock (GIL) which runs only one thread at a time. If you are using multiple processes which can run code in parallel then it won't be of course.